# Magento 2.4.6-p3 Checkout not longer detects registered account

Tags: magento2.4.6

I have a problem after update to M2.4.6-p3.
On Checkout with registered but not logged user after email inserting, the registered account will now not automatically detected.

For example, the screencasts for M2.4.6 and M2.4.6-p3:

Magento 2.4.6 -
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/24352710?key=6e1dac0fe89ea29f5bc4588b6c38ad64

Magento 2.4.6-p3 -
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/24352800?key=7a4da78a4cf1c62acf2c519f996f1b4e

Any idea?

Comment: Hi @iskander, I also experienced the same issue before, and it was due to the overridden checkout JS/HTML code. Have you overridden any checkout JS/HTML code on your end?

Comment: I tested this on new installed M2.4.6-p3 with sample data, without custom themes, without custom modules and another custom code.

Comment: So is it working fine without custom theme & custom code?

Comment: No, same not working

Comment: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/24382472?key=cbd9424b9ec21b9689c663d0076934e2

Comment: I have added an answer. Please check the solution once. it will fix your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From v2.4.6-p1 and above, Magento changed the default behavior of the `isEmailAvailable` API call. It now always returns `true` by default for security reason.

You can enable the original behavior from the configuration :

- Stores > Configuration > Sales > Checkout > Checkout Options
- In the "Enable Guest Checkout Login" option, uncheck "Use system value" and set it to "Yes"

Comment: thanks, it s working

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the guest user login option from the below path:

Goto Backend -> Store -> Configuration -> Sales -> Checkout -> Checkout Options -> Enable Guest Checkout Login

**Here is the Screenshot:**

[image]